# Dynamically setting commit-interval in spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

My requirement is to set the commit interval in spring batch dynamically in my reader class.

Example:

1. group1 of  10 messages
2. group2 of 4 messages
3. group3 of 8 messages.

I want to set the commit-interval for each group dynamically to the size of messages.

I know there are two options:

1. Through jobparameter
2. Through completion policy.

I have tried the second option and I am getting a number format exception.

Could you please provide me a complete working example of the above options?

Comment: Please share the xml

Comment: Are you using a java configuration or a xml configuration? Please share some of the code and configuration you have tried.